# Static UITableView not showing in a UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` with a bunch of static `UITableViewCells` which should work as a `settings` screen. I've setup all static cells and I'm trying to embed that `UITableViewController` into a `UIViewController` but all I get is a blank `UITableView` and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the code, in the `SettingsTVC` (or the parent view controller). The child view controller doesn't contain any code yet. It's just connected as a class in `UIStoryboard`.

```
class SettingsVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create child VC
    let settingsChildTVC = SettingsChildTVC()

    // Set child VC
    self.addChildViewController(settingsChildTVC)

    // Add child VC's view to parent
    self.view.addSubview(settingsChildTVC.view)

    // Register child VC
    settingsChildTVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    // Setup constraints for layout
    settingsChildTVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    settingsChildTVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    settingsChildTVC.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    settingsChildTVC.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    settingsChildTVC.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    settingsChildTVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot something. The static `UITableViews` only work from `UIStoryboards`. They can only be defined in a `UIStoryboard` and must be instantiated from that storyboard using: `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`